# MySQL SELECT with an extra column containing a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select

I used to know how to do this, but I can’t seem to remember or find the answer.

I want to return data from a table and then just add an extra column with a set value (which does not need to be saved). So, it is not an `UPDATE` issue.  Just a `SELECT` with that extra column.

Original table:

```
|  id  |   col1   |   col2   |
|  1   |  value1  |  value2  |
```

Return something like this:

```
|  id  |   col1   |   col2   ||    tmpCol    |
|  1   |  value1  |  value2  ||    12:48     |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
SELECT id, col1, col2, '12:48' AS tempCol
```

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks.  Turns out the error was somewhere else.  This seems to happen to me a lot.  Just after I post a question here, I find the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
select id,col1,col2, '12.48'  as tempcol
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. alter table TableName add column columnName date ; 
note, put the exact  table name in the "TableName that i defined" that u want to add  the column and put the column name where i defined the "columnName"